# Simple analytical model for fluid flow in "Mushroom cloud"

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, flow, potential-flow

In [potential flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushroom_cloud#/media/File:Mushroom_cloud.svg) theory there are simple analytical models (formulas) for velocity-field of elementary features (like source, sink, dipole, vortex etc.)

- Is it possible to write simple analytical expression for flow (i.e. velocity field $\vec v(\vec r)$) inside ascending [mushroom cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushroom_cloud#Physics) (i.e. bouble of hot air creating single toroidal vortex)?
- Is it possible to analytically integrate motion in such velocity field, in order to obtain explicit formula for time dependent **tranjectory** $\vec r(\vec r_0,t)$ of each test particle (each fluid element) in the flow depending on initial position $\vec r_o$ and time $t$ ?

Note: In reality this will involve turbulences making the shape more complicated (more vorticies). I don't want to model these turbulences,(see. [Rayleigh–Taylor instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Taylor_instability#/media/File:HD-Rayleigh-Taylor.gif)), just the single primary toroidal vortex on top of column of up-drafting air.

[image]